# Using a dictionary as an answer key for user input

Tags: python, dictionary

This is meant to only break out of the loop when the user enters a file extension that is in the dictionary:

```
def ext_input():
    ext_dict = {'doc', 'docx', 'pdf', 'rtf', 'txt', 'wps', 'csv'}
    while True:
        print('Enter the file extension (.pdf, .txt, etc..) type "help" for a list of extensions')
        fileExt = input()
        if fileExt == "help":
            print(ext_dict)
            return
        elif fileExt != ext_dict:
            print('Please enter a correct file extension (.pdf, .txt, etc..) type "help" for a list of extensions')
        else:
            print("\"%s\" has been selected" % fileExt)
            break
```

Still relatively new to python, any pointers in the right direction would be great

Comment: Could you please clarify what your question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `help_dict` is not a `dict`, it's a `set`.

Second: you're comparing a string with a set - which *of course* won't never ever compare equal. Testing if a set contains an element is done with the `in` operator: `if something in myset:` - and for non-appartenance you simply use `not in`. IOW, you want:

```
elif fileExt not in ext_dict:
   # XXXX
```

Comment: I knew it was something as simple as that, the more you know! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `ext_dict` should be a list rather than a dictionary (which it isn't, see Bruno's answer), which allows for this modified code:

```
def ext_input():
    ext_dict = ['doc', 'docx', 'pdf', 'rtf', 'txt', 'wps', 'csv']
    while True:
        print('Enter the file extension (.pdf, .txt, etc..) type "help" for a list of extensions')
        fileExt = input()
        if fileExt == "help":
            print(ext_dict)
            return
        elif fileExt not in ext_dict:
            print('Please enter a correct file extension (.pdf, .txt, etc..) type "help" for a list of extensions')
        else:
            print("\"%s\" has been selected" % fileExt)
            break
```

Comment: it's not a `dict` actually, it's a `set`, and as such is the right type to use for quick containment test - `elt in set` is O(1), while `elt in list` is O(n).

Comment: Yes, but my answer is based on the assumption that he did think `ext_dict` was a dictionary ;-)
However, thank you for that detail, I was wondering if there was a performance cost to using either a list or a set. This doesn't have any real impact here of course, the list being so small, but good to know none the less!
Will amend my answer. Thanks!